# How to use a left join and self join in SQL Server in a single query?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have the following tables:

1. tbl_Patient_Master

[image: Patient Table]

2. tbl_Doctor_Master

[image: Doctor Table]

3. tbl_Appointment_Creation

[image: Appointment Creation Table]

I want the result as follows:

[image: Table showing all Patient Names with Same Doctor Names]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some code.

Comment: It's a `JOIN` FROM _Doctor to Appointment_ and from _Appointment to Patient_. What have you tried?

Comment: Why do you think you would need a self join?

Comment: You can use `select from tbl_Appointment_creation` and then `left join to tbl_patient_master` and `left join to tbl_doctor_master`. You do not need a self join

Comment: I want to group them with Same Doctor names. Please refer the last image attached with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `SELF JOIN`

```
SELECT A.Booking_ID, D.Doctor_name, P.Patient_Name, A.Booking_Date, A.Comments 
FROM Appointment A
LEFT JOIN Doctor D ON A.Doctor_ID = D.Doctor_ID
LEFT JOIN Patient ON A.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID
GROUP BY D.Doctor_name, P.Patient_Name, A.Booking_Date, A.Booking_ID, A.Comments
```

Comment: Your query is giving the Doctor and patient Names Columns, but I want to group them with Same Doctor names. Please refer the last image attached with the question.

Comment: @FlaSh9293 Please check and let me know whether it is working or not?

Comment: Column 'tbl_Appointment_Creation.Booking_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @FlaSh9293 Plz check now.

Answer (score 0):

to get `patients` with same `doctor`, we need to get those `appointments` having same doctors first.

```
select t1.Booking_Id, t2.Doctor_Name, t3.Patient_name, t1.Date, t1.Comments
from Appointment t1
join Doctor t2 on t1.Doctor_ID = t2.Doctor_ID
join Patient t3 on t1.Patient_ID = t3.Patient_ID
inner join ( 
    select count(1), d.Doctor_name
    from Appointment a
    join Doctor d on a.Doctor_ID = d.Doctor_ID
    join Patient p on a.Patient_ID = p.Patient_ID
    group by a.Doctor_name
    having count(1) > 1) t on t.Doctor_name = t2.Doctor_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select A.Booking_ID as Booking_ID
     , B.Doctor_Name as Doctor_Name
     , C.Patient_Name as Patient_Name
     , A.Booking_Date as Date
     , A.Comments as Comments
  from Appointment_Creation A
     , Doctor B
     , Patient C
 where A.Doctor_ID = B.Doctor_ID
   and A.Patient_ID = C.Patient_ID
```

no need to use left join, but I'd like to recommend to use foreign keys

Comment: Your query is giving the Doctor and patient Names Columns, but I want to group them with Same Doctor names. Please refer the last image attached with the question.